# What is the best way to run in parallel the same myfile.py?

Tags: python

I want to run `myfile.py` among multiple process instead to execute it from mutliple command line like python myfile.py . So I create the following code:

```
import os                                                                       
from multiprocessing import Pool                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
processes = ('myfile.py')                                    
                                                   
                                                                                
def run_process(process):                                                             
    os.system('python {}'.format(process))                                       
                                                                                
                                                                                
pool = Pool(processes=3)                                                        
pool.map(run_process, processes)
```

When i execute the code i get the following:

```
python can't open file 'm': [error 2] No such file or directory
python can't open file 'y': [error 2] No such file or directory
...
python can't open file 'e': [error 2] No such file or directory
```

How I can solve this problem? What is the best way to run in parallel the same myfile.py

Comment: Usually, you could just run `os.system` in a loop no need for multiprocessing.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer It's worth noting that `os.system` has been superseded by the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. It's probably best not to point beginners towards outdated tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
processes = ('myfile.py',)
```

(the comma is required)

As otherwise python treats it as characters of the string rather than a tuple.

Comment: thank you. i get python can't open file 'myfile.p': [error 2] No such file or directory. i dont if it is because i have if__main__='main'; in myfile.py

Comment: Is there a chance there is a typo in the file name?

Comment: i tried without a if__main__='main'; in myfile.py the code work otherwise no. it eecute the file but say at the end python can't open file 'myfile.py': [error 2] No such file or directory

Comment: the 'myfile.py' file is probably OK. I think the issue is in the script that does the parallelization. Could you please double check the line `processes = ('myfile.py',)`. I think the file name can be misspelled there.

Comment: i put in myfile.py only one instruction print('hello"). so the code shows hello 3 times but at the end they say python can't open file 'myfile.py': [error 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Try replace that line with the following: processes = ['myfile.py'] * 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228772/discussion-between-bib-and-moon-413).

Answer (score 0):

You're actually *evaluating* a single line, rather than creating a list of one item. This is because the `tuple` is being accidentally applied as a parenthesis set. Change this:

```
processes = ('myfile.py')
```

to:

```
processes = ('myfile.py', ) # It's a tuple now
```